# How do I put an image above the content box?

Tags: html, css

So I am extremely new to coding and I am doing this for my career school capstone project and I am running into a lot of problems. Mainly two: How to put the image above the content box? (even with a transparent background).

Here is my Code:

```css
/*Header Begins*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color:     #FFDAB9;
}

li, a, button {
  font-family: "Monserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.logo {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav__links{
  list-style: none;
}
.nav__links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}
.nav__links li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.nav__links li a:hover {
  color: #fd56ed;
}
button {
  padding: 9px 25px;
  background-color: #79cdf6;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
button:hover{
  background-color: rgba(0,136,169,1);
}
header img {
  width: 13%;
  height: 13%;
}
/*Header Ends*/
/*body begins*/

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  
}
.box {
  margin: 30px auto 70px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
#box img:logo.png {
    opacity: 1;
}

/*body ends*/
/*footer begins*/
footer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position: reflexive;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.nav_link_footer li a:hover {
  list-style: none;
  color: #fd56ed;
}
.nav_link_footer li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
        <body>
              <header>
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Alt Image"></a>
                    <nav>
                      <ul class="nav__links">
                          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                          <li><a href="Reward.html">Catalog</a></li>
                          <li><a href="Earn.html">Clothes</a></li>
                          <li><a href="Spins.html">Corner</a></li>
                        </ul>
                  </nav>
                <a class="cta" href="Contact.html"><button>Contact Us</button><a>
              </header>
           ***  <div class="container">
                  <div class="box">
                        <img src="images/logo.png">
                    </div>
                </div> ***
       <footer>
          <ul class="nav_link_footer">
             <li><p>Marshion&copy</p></li>
             <li><a href = "mailto: ">Email Us</a></li>
             <li><p>YouTube: @Marshion!</p></li>
             <li><p>Instagram: @Marshion</p></li>
             <li><p>Facebook: @Marshion</p></li>
           </ul>
        </footer>
        </body>
</html>
```

The white box appears next to the image. I wanted it to be inside the box. I also wanted to box to have it's own set of opacity and colors. Which I know that I need to adjust my DIV boxes and create better ones but I'm not sure where to start #1, and I don't necessarily have any guidance on how to do so.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't put code between the `</body>` and `</html>`

Comment: You may also want to remove that email address from your sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first at all:

If you want to make the background of the box a bit transparent then you should not give an `opacity: 0.5;` but a `background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);`

---

Then I also saw this in your CSS code:

[image: class and id]

You used a class for the box in the HTML. For the box-image in CSS you used an ID. And if you want to address the image in the Box class then you don't say `.box img:logo.png` but `.box img`

**The correct CSS code should look like this:**

[image: correct css]

---

### Here is the whole revised code again. If something is missing then let us know:

```css
/*Header Begins*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color:     #FFDAB9;
}

li, a, button {
  font-family: "Monserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.logo {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav__links{
  list-style: none;
}
.nav__links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}
.nav__links li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.nav__links li a:hover {
  color: #fd56ed;
}
button {
  padding: 9px 25px;
  background-color: #79cdf6;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
button:hover{
  background-color: rgba(0,136,169,1);
}
header img {
  width: 13%;
  height: 13%;
}
/*Header Ends*/
/*body begins*/

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  
}
.box {
  margin: 30px auto 70px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.box img {
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

/*body ends*/
/*footer begins*/
footer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position: reflexive;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.nav_link_footer li a:hover {
  list-style: none;
  color: #fd56ed;
}
.nav_link_footer li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
        <body>
              <header>
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Alt Image"></a>
                    <nav>
                      <ul class="nav__links">
                          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                          <li><a href="Reward.html">Catalog</a></li>
                          <li><a href="Earn.html">Clothes</a></li>
                          <li><a href="Spins.html">Corner</a></li>
                        </ul>
                  </nav>
                <a class="cta" href="Contact.html"><button>Contact Us</button><a>
              </header>
           ***  <div class="container">
                  <div class="box">
                        <img src="images/logo.png">
                    </div>
                </div> ***
       <footer>
          <ul class="nav_link_footer">
             <li><p>Marshion&copy</p></li>
             <li><a href = "mailto: ">Email Us</a></li>
             <li><p>YouTube: @Marshion!</p></li>
             <li><p>Instagram: @Marshion</p></li>
             <li><p>Facebook: @Marshion</p></li>
           </ul>
        </footer>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It did! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```css
#box img:logo.png {
    float: none; 
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I have just one, I am just using the second one as an example for the image on the page. and the ID is the ```.box```.

Comment: I implemented that code, and it has not done anything to the image